# SQL Server 2008 R2, Mixed arguments in a computed column

Tags: sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

I'm a noob guys, so don't be too harsh.

New to the forum, read around and couldn't fin d an answer.  Maybe someone here knows if this works or not.

Building a computed column in the management studio, We'll call it total.  When I enter this equation, it works:

```
Liquor + Beer + Wine + Food + NonAlc
```

When I enter this equation it fails and returns null:

```
Liquor + Beer + Wine + Food + NonAlc + NonAlc - Voucher
```

All fields are identical data types (money). Can't get it to work with mixed arguments. Anyone have any suggestions for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.  I had a NULL in the voucher field.  :-P

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Feel free to either add an official answer to your question if it will benefit others, or delete the question altogether.  To be honest, though, since the answer was very specific to your situation (being that you overlooked a particular value), I would be inclined to lean towards the latter.

Comment: Thanks Derek.  Hopefully the next time you see me it will include less facepalm on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
ISNULL(Liquor, 0) + ISNULL(Beer, 0) + ISNULL(Wine, 0) + ISNULL(Food, 0) 
      + ISNULL(NonAlc, 0) + ISNULL(NonAlc, 0) - ISNULL(Voucher, 0)
```

Comment: Will use that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
Concat(Liquor , Beer ,Wine ,food ,NonAlc ,NonAlc - Voucher)